# Excluding unknown number of multiple directories from find search (Unix)

Tags: regex, shell, unix, find

I have a shell script that is looking for some files and it works fine:

```
find . -name "*.sh"
```

But here we go: I want to exclude a few (let's say 3 - dir1, dir2 and dir3) directories from this search. So I looked for ways to do this, but I only found solutions that were "static". That means I found a lot of solutions explaining how to exclude exactly 3 directories from the find search. But cannot be sure about the number of directories to exclude - maybe I need to exclude 3, maybe 5 or even 20. I would like to read the directories from an input file as strings (I've got that reading logic so far) and would like to use find excluding those files dynamically.

To clarify this: I have a string like this: '/home/dir1,/dir2,./dir3,./sub/dir4' and I do not know how many directories will be contained by this string, but I would like to exclude all of them.

Is there a solution using a REGEX parameter or something? I am currently working on a SUN solaris and am using the sh-Shell.

Every help/hints will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-prune` to exclude paths until you are left with only paths you do want.

```
find . -iregex '.*/.git/.*' -prune -o -type d -name 'CVS' -prune -o ... whatever -print
```

I am using different predicates to demonstrate that you have the full support of the predicates supported by `find`.  Out if these, `-iregex` applies a regex against the full path name case-insensitively; `-type d -name CVS` matches directories whose name is precisely `CVS`, etc.  Obviously, see [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for many more.  Add as many as you like or need in order to solve your problem.

I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamically" but if I guess correctly what you mean, it doesn't get more dynamic than having a command line which selects which directories to exclude based on a set of rules.  If you want to exclude directories whose fourth character is W, add `-o -name '???W*' -prune`.  If you have more conditions, add more conditions.

At the other end of the spectrum, you can create a completely static command by enumerating the directories you want to exclude.  You can probably create a script which creates the final `find` command line for you, something like

```
printf '%\n' one/directory path/to/another hey/yes/one/more etc/and/so/forth |
sed "s%.*%-type d -path '&' -prune -o %" |
xargs -i find . {} print
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you fast answer! I read about the -prune option, but how do I use this, if I do not know how many directories I need to exclude? This would be a nice solution, but I assume that I cannot built this command dynamically depending on how many directories I need to exclude.

Comment: @Pat I answered how to dynamically ignore dirs using a `! -path` option, if this doesn't work for you but `-prune` does, combine both answers. Where I insert `! -path` you should simply insert `-prune -o -type d -name` instead.

Comment: Updated the answer to hopefully cover more bases.

Answer (score 0):

**Exclude dirs from file**

Just create your find command from the file:

```
exclude=' ! -path "./'$(paste -s -d'#' dirstoexclude | sed 's/#/\/\*" ! -path "\.\//g')'/*"'
find . -type f ${exclude}
```

Store your dirs in `dirsttoexclude` without leading `./` and trailing `/*`, they will be added. Example usage:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ mkdir test1 test2 test3
$ touch test1/a test2/b test3/c
$ find -type f
./test2/b
./test1/a
./test3/c
$ cat exclude\ dirs
test1
test2
$ exclude=' ! -path "./'$(paste -s -d'#' "exclude dirs" | sed 's/#/\/\*" ! -path "\.\//g')'/*"'
$ find . -type f $exclude
./test3/c
```

You can wrap it in a shell script, it should also work when only one dir is in the file.

Note: for this to work there cannot be a `#` in your file names, use another separation char if this can happen.=

Edit: Since you have the dirs in a comma separated string, the solution is even easier. Just use bash substitution for this:

```
exclude=' ! -path "./'${string//,/\/*\" ! -path \"./}'/*"'
```

**Use regex**

You an also use regex in `find`, so all you need to do is check if there exists a regex that can match your needs (which is probable). You use it like this:

```
 find -regextype sed -regex '.*some *regex.*'
```